# Pytest: specifying multiple naming conventions for functions

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

I want to test functions in a class and for some reason I couldn't name them like **test_***. This is how my class looks like:

```
class SegmentationSuite:
    """Benchmark for segmentation routines in scikit-image."""
    def setup(self):
        self.image = np.random.random((400, 400, 100))
        self.image[:200, :200, :] += 1
        self.image[300:, 300:, :] += 0.5

    def time_slic_basic(self):
        segmentation.slic(self.image, enforce_connectivity=False)

    def peakmem_setup(self):
        pass

    def peakmem_slic_basic(self):
        segmentation.slic(self.image, enforce_connectivity=False)
```

So, there are three sets of functions: `time_*`, `setup` and `peakmem`. After looking at the pytest docs, I found out https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/pythoncollection.html#changing-naming-conventions

So, I created a `setup.cfg` file and added the following to it:

```
[tool:pytest]
python_files=benchmark_*.py
python_classes=*Suite
python_functions=time_*, setup, peakmem*
```

but it doesn't work.

How do I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it
`python_functions=time_* setup peakmem*`. Specifying multiple glob patterns separated with blank space.